# i am begginer in django ,

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

**Q1-> I don't know why  "GroupMember" model is not showing in admin panel. 
 Q2-> why "members = models.ManyToManyField(User,through="GroupMember")" field is also not showing in 
 admin panel**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
# from accounts.models import User

import misaka

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()


from django import template
register = template.Library()



class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    description_html = models.TextField(editable=False, default='', blank=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User,through="GroupMember")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        self.description_html = misaka.html(self.description)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("groups:single", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})


    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]


class GroupMember(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name="memberships")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='user_groups')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("group", "user")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUSRL.png)

Comment: did you register your models in ***`admin.py`*** ?

Comment: `from django.contrib import admin from . import models class GroupMemberInline(admin.TabularInline): model = models.GroupMember admin.site.register(models.Group) `this is my admin.py . I don't know what is the use of (admin.TabularInline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should add your app to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
...
'your_app',
...
]
```

Then you have to register your models in your_app/admin.py like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Group, GroupMember

admin.site.register(Group)
admin.site.register(GroupMember)
```

Comment: `from django.contrib import admin

from . import models


class GroupMemberInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.GroupMember



admin.site.register(models.Group)` this is my admin.py . I don't know what is the use of (admin.TabularInline)